# Flexible MySQL Search Queries

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table of US cities and their corresponding states:

```
City          State_Abbr     State
Charlotte     NC             North Carolina
Fort Mill     SC             South Carolina
Columbia      SC             South Carolina
Dallas        TX             Texas
...           ...            ...
```

Of course the table is much larger but you get the idea. Now i'd like users to be able to perform searches on this table through a single input on an HTML page. A user looking for Charlotte, NC might enter any of the following:

```
charlotte north carolina
charlotte, nc
north carolina charlotte
nc charlotte
charlotte
...
```

Or they might misspell a word cherlote instead of charlotte...

What is the best way to approach setting up a search query? Should I remove all but characters in the search string and split by spaces and then perform a SOUNDS LIKE on each field in the table? In the case of an input such as charlotte north carolina how would I determine that charlotte is the city portion and north carolina the state?

Is it possible to do all of this in plain SQL query or will I need to perform some pre-processing via something like Java or Javascript prior to building the actual query?

Just looking for the most flexible approach. Using too many OR's seems to return very random results.

I don't want to limit this question to java only, but if I need to pre-process Java is my most comfortable language.

Comment: Please have a look at full text search.

Answer (score 0):

I would split at the spaces then use LIKE on all the possible columns. Then if there is a record that has the most hits, I would choose that one. It may be possible to use the ORDER BY to do the counts for you so you don't have to do it in PHP and the best record can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

First would have to do a split to the input value:

**Input 1:** `SPLIT (charlotte north carolina) => [charlotte, north carolina]`

**Input 2:** `SPLIT (charlotte nc) => [nc, charlotte]`

Second would have to concatenate all possible columns to see them as the same element:

```
SELECT CONCAT (City, State_Abbr, State) as all_columns
```

...

Third would have to generate dynamically query this way, depending on the values ​​resulting from the first step:

**For Input 1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (City, State_Abbr, State) as all_columns
FROM Table_Cities_Name
WHERE upper (all_columns) LIKE upper ('%charlotte%')
OR upper (all_columns) LIKE upper ('%north%')
OR upper (all_columns) LIKE upper ('%carolina%')
```

**For Input 2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT  CONCAT (City, State_Abbr, State) as all_columns
FROM Table_Cities_Name
WHERE upper (all_columns) LIKE upper ('%nc%')
OR upper (all_columns) LIKE upper ('%charlotte%')
```

**Note:** The examples are not case sensitive. If you want to have the examples case sensitive,  eliminates upper function in querys

> Edited for added DISTINCT clause in queries.

Regards

Comment: This unfortunately returns way too many results. I think i'll have to parse the input and perform validations prior to querying.

Answer (score 0):

Try a full text index.  You'll have to read the manual to see if it fits your case but usually it helps with the fuzzy stuff.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html